# jQuery animation changing window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am trying to build a sidebar which sweeps in from the left of the screen. I have the menu element floating left with a width = 40% and margin-left = -40%.

When I swipe or press the button for the sidebar to appear, the pages resizes      itself and zooms out to accommodate the sidebar. I can stop this happening if I stop the container from having a width of 100%, however, I want the content to         be the full width of the page.

This is how I'm moving the sidebar:

```
$("allContainer").animate({left: '40%'});
```

I have my the code [here](//jsfiddle.net/bc4kau0w/) on JSFiddle.

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: Do you want the sidebar to slide on top of the content when it slides out?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are animating the container `allContainer` that also holds your content so everything is moving left. Just animate the `sidebar` in.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bc4kau0w/3/

CSS:

```
#sidebar {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: blue;
  margin-left: -40%;
  position: absolute;
}

button {
  float: right;
}
```

JS:

```
var isMoved = false;
$("button").click(function() {
    if (isMoved) {
        $("#sidebar").animate({
            left: '0px'
        });
    } else {
        $("#sidebar").animate({
            left: '40%'
        });
    }
    isMoved = !isMoved;
});
```

And in case I misunderstood and you don't want the sidebar to cover anything here is a fiddle showing your content shrinking when the sidebar expands so nothing is covered. Either way the main issue, as I saw it, was animating the `allContainer` instead of the smaller pieces within it.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bc4kau0w/4/